# How can I test an email address to see if it is valid

Tags: email, internet

How can I test an email address to see if it is valid?  For example, Facebook allows you to create an account with an incorrect email address after verifying with a phone number.  Is it possible to check for a valid email address and if so how?

Comment: Those are all *technically* valid e-mail addresses. See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696. Facebook will send you a confirmation e-mail though, so if you enter a non-existing address you cannot use its services: https://www.facebook.com/help/376335499080938 – questions about web applications are off topic though.

Comment: *Precisely* define what you mean by "valid" and then see if the email address meets that definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the operating System is Windows you can verify by doing the following

To do it Follow these steps

1.Open Command Prompt

2.Find the exchanger of the domain  By nslookup

```
   nslookup – q=mx gmail.com
```

3.Connect to mail Server using telnet

```
   telnet gmail.com 25
```

4.once you get the response

type some message hi ,hello

```
   mail from: <youremail@gmail.com>
   rcpt to: <test12345666@gmail.com>
```

5.If you get response code `550` then the recipient address is invalid

6.If email is vaild  the mail server would respond back with code `250`

Alternatively you could test using some online email checking tools like [mailtester](http://mailtester.com/) .

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways that I have seen sites validate email addresses.

1. test for valid email address syntax of the form username@domain.com
2. test for 1 and if it passes then test that the domain is valid by doing a whois lookup of the domain.
   `#whois domain.com;`
3. test for both of the above and if the address passes, then send a unique link to the email address that has to be visited by the user or send a unique code that has to be entered into a web form.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696 you can end up wtih regular expressions like this ones http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

finally test your regexp at:
[www.regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Ba-z0-9!#$%25&%27*%2b/=?%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D%7E-%5D%2b%28?:%5C.%5Ba-z0-9!#$%25&%27*%2b/=?%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D%7E-%5D%2b%29*@%28?:%5Ba-z0-9%5D%28?:%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D%29?%5C.%29%2b%5Ba-z0-9%5D%28?:%5Ba-z0-9-%5D*%5Ba-z0-9%5D%29?&input=example.user@department.company.com%0A)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way I found is online email validity checking tools like [vefify email](http://verify-email.org/) and [email checker](http://tools.email-checker.com/)

Comment: I'm inclined to like the first tool, but I tried an email address on my domain that I know exists and another one that I know doesn't, and they both say "UNKNOWN". So it looks like it doesn't work.